# Struggling to find formula to find if a certain words come up for the same account

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

[image]

The table above is an example. Lets say I only have Column 1 & 2 and want to create the yellow headers.

I'm trying to figure out a formula to look for the fruit and return a 1 if the header of that column can be matched to the fruit.

Once I figure that formula out I will then delete duplicates in column A and end with this:

[image]

I tried using something like Index and Match formula but that does not return the "1" on the same rows.

Usually the data is reversed and I can use countif but I'm lost on what formula to use.

Essential in cell C2, I want to find if C1 can be found in the B Column with Apple being the criteria. And the same for D2, E2, F2. It's hard to explain but I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the formula you've been looking for. Enter it inC2 and copy right and down as far as required.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(Data,,1),$A2,INDEX(Data,,2),C$1)
```

I'm using a range I called `Data` in the formula which comprises A2:B7 in your example. In real life you would make it dynamic or even replace INDEX(Data,,1) with $A:$A. It's a decision about quality, not functionality. In programming the better "quality" requires less time for maintenance. Therefore it's subjective.

The formula returns a lot of zeroes. You can get rid of them with cell formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot table for:

[image]

zz